# Does protobuf-net generated binary compatible with Google specs

Tags: protobuf-net

Actually I want to serialize my data using Google's java implementation and then deserialize using C# implementation?
I have chosen protobuf-net as it seems to be more stable (proto# is still v0.9 or I would have gone for it). Before I start working on it I wanted to be sure that I can achieve this (serializing data using java implementation and deserializing it using protobuf-net). Or is there any list of methods that are specific to protobuf-net implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the same API on multiple platforms, [Jon Skeet's implementation](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/) may be more appropriate to you. The difference is that protobuf-net is designed around common C# development patterns, for example it doesn't demand that you use the generated types (you can use your own, exactly like you can with `DataContractSerializer`, `XmlSerializer`, etc) - and it supports some BCL concepts directly.

The two should be 100% compatible on the wire, but here's some **API** differences:

- direct support for `DateTime`, `TimeSpan`, `Guid` etc (described by the contracts in bcl.proto in the zip)
- support for inheritance (mapped as nested data on the wire)
- support for your own types
- support for *mutable* types (rather than the builder/immutable pair)
- support for serialization callbacks
- (possibly a few others - do you need a 100% complete list?)

The one you are most likely to notice is inheritance. Simply: don't use this if you are planning to use interop. I have tried to make it very explicit in the intellisense if you are doing something that will use .NET-specific tricks, but if you start from a .proto it won't use these *anyway* (it should be portable-friendly).

Comment: I would be generating all the code from .porto file. So it should be portable.

Comment: @cornerback84 - FYI, it's "proto" (as in protocol) not "porto".  You've made that typo a few times, so I thought it deserved clearing up :)

Answer (score 0):

All the google serializations are wire compatible, and although protobuf-net isn't written by Google, it [claims to be wire-compatible](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/).

In addition, there is a page of compatible C# APIs linked from [Google's documentation.](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/reference/other.html)

Comment: All implementations should be wire compatible.

Comment: @Marc Gravell - Thanks.  I found the description that protobuf-net is wire-compatible with Google's format ( http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/ ).  The mistyped name 'portobuf-net' threw me off, I thought it was a different project.  Edited my answer for clarity.